# Embedding a <p> tag within an anchor tag will not allow me to trigger the href

Tags: html, css, button, tags, click

I am attempting to create a menu using `<a>` tags. I put a span inside the `<a>` tag in order to style it.

```
<dt onClick = "changeColor_one()">
    <a class="accordionTitle" href="#" id = "first_acor" 
       style="background-color: #00ADF7">
       <p style="display:inline;" id="smaller_text">Are there any minimum time requirements to join?</p>
    </a>
</dt>
```

Clicking on any part of the `dt` that is not the actual text itself will trigger the content. Any idea why clicking on the text does nothing? Here is the styling for `#smaller_text`

```
#smaller_text
{
    position: relative;
    top:-20px;
    font-size:22px;
    float:left;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: is <dt onClick = "changeColor_one()"> triggering any event in the first place. onClick is not a valid attribute.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't nest two elements with click handlers inside each other.

Comment: @Rash In what way is onClick not a valid attribute?

Comment: @IanFreeman Sorry. I got confused with onClick and onclick. Apparantly html attributes are not case sensitive as I thought them they would. Anyways, I ran your code and there is a possibility that your <p> tag is overshadowing your <a> tag and hence you are not able to click it. In any case, if you wish to style the text inside <a> tag, you can simply do that in style attribute inside <a> tag. E.g. <a style="font-size: 22px;">My TExt</a>

Comment: @Rash attribute names are only case sensitive in an XML environment (that is, XHTML served up with any XML mime type).